# EF Core Projecting optional property in jsonb column

Tags: npgsql, ef-core-3.1

I need to project some fields from jsonb column where few of them are optional

I'm using EF Core 3.1 and npgsl  and so far I got this

```
 var shipments = _dbContext.Shipments.Select(x => new
            {
                ShipmentNo= x.ShipmentNumber,
                ReportNum = x.ShipmentData.RootElement.GetProperty("reportNumber"),
                ShipmentValue= x.ShipmentData.RootElement.GetProperty("shipmentMetadata").GetProperty("value").GetString(),
            }
```

However `value` is optional and this is throwing exception. I see `.TryGetProperty(...)` method but it requires output variable and, I presume, its evaluation on server side. I wonder if there is way to handle this so query runs completely in Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've forgotten to add GetInt32 (or whatever the type is) for `reportNumber`, just like you have a GetString after the `shipmentMetadata`. In order for this to be translatable to SQL, you need to tell the provider which type you expect to come out of the JSON element.